# What (kind of) data is lost when using REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

after having some trouble with my sql server 2012 I could only fix the data inconsistencies using DBCC CHECKDB (xxx, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS). The option's name implies, that there will (possibly) be a data loss, when the database is repaired.

What is the data that is lost and how harmfull is the loss?

For example, take a look at this log message:

> The off-row data node at page (1:705), slot 0, text ID 328867287793664 is not referenced.

If that node is not referenced and it is this node, that causes the inconsistency, delete it. That shouldn't hurt anyone. Is that the kind of data loss MS is talking about?

Best regards,
Sascha

Comment: Joyfully, it's not (so far as I'm aware) actually documented. So it could do (either today, or in some future version, service pack, hotfix, etc) practically *anything* if that was thought to be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Paul Randal's blog post for some additional insight into the implications of running DBCC CHECKDB with REPOAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS:

> > REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS is the repair level that DBCC CHECKDB recommends when it finds corruptions. This is because fixing nearly
> >     anything that’s not a minor non-clustered index issue requires
> >     deleting something to repair it. So, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS will
> >     delete things. This means it will probably delete some of your data as
> >     well. If, for instance it finds a corrupt record on a data page, it
> >     may end up having to delete the entire data page, including all the
> >     other records on the page, to fix the corruption. That could be a lot
> >     of data. For this reason, the repair level name was carefully chosen.
> >     You can’t type in REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS without realizing that you’re
> >     probably going to lose some data as part of the operation.
>
> I’ve been asked why this is. The purpose of repair is not to save user
>   data. The purpose of repair is to make the database structurally
>   consistent as fast as possible (to limit downtime) and correctly (to
>   avoid making things worse). This means that repairs have to be
>   engineered to be fast and reliable operations that will work in every
>   circumstance. The simple way to do this is to delete what’s broken and
>   fix up everything that linked to (or was linked from) the thing being
>   deleted – whether a record or page. Trying to do anything more
>   complicated would increase the chances of the repair not working, or
>   even making things worse.
>
> The ramifications of this are that running REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS can
>   lead to the same effect on your data as rebuilding a transaction log
>   with in-flight transactions altering user data – your business logic,
>   inherent and constraint-enforced relationships between tables, and the
>   basic logical integrity of your user data could all be broken. BUT,
>   the database is now structurally consistent and SQL Server can run on
>   it without fear of hitting a corruption that could cause a crash.
>
> To continue the contrived example from above, imagine your bank
>   checking and savings accounts just happen to be stored on the same
>   data page in the bank’s SQL Server database. The new DBA doesn’t
>   realize that backups are necessary for disaster recovery and data
>   preservation and so isn’t taking any. Disaster strikes again in the
>   form of the work crew outside the data-center accidentally cutting the
>   power and the machine hosting SQL Server powers down. This time, one
>   of the drives has a problem while powering down and a page write
>   doesn’t complete – causing a torn page. Unfortunately, it’s the page
>   holding your bank accounts. As the DBA doesn’t have any backups, the
>   only alternative to fix the torn-page is to run
>   REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS. For this error, it will delete the page, and
>   does so. In the process, everything else on the page is also lost,
>   including your bank accounts!!

Source: [Corruption: Last resorts that people try first…](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-last-resorts-that-people-try-first/)